# IE8 fancybox content denied

Tags: internet-explorer-8, fancybox

When i did everything for the **login/registration in magento** i just got into biggest problem on IE. I didnt realized that IE could deny the iframe content on fancybox.

Here is the screenshot which shows what IE displayed.

How can i force the fancybox to load site data into IE8 fancybox iframe.

Using magento and ssl is enabled. So is that could be a problem why IE says the page is denied on iframe.

This is the fancybox code i used for registration

```
w49("a#header-register").fancybox({
                                'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
                                'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
                                'speedIn'       :   800, 
                                'speedOut'      :   400, 
                                'width'         :   740, 
                                'height'        :   400, 
                                'type'          :   'iframe',
                                'overlayShow'   :   true
                            });
```

Please some one tell em a solution.

[image: Here is the screenshot which shows what IE displayed.]

Comment: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" /> 
Added this meta line to force IE7 mode, but still having same issue, its like http/https mixed content magento problem